# Implementing traverse function in one iteration in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, traversal

It combines a list of `Option`s into one `Option` containing a list of all the `Some` values in the original list. If the original list contains `None` even once, the result of the function should be `None`, otherwise the result should be `Some` with a list of all the values. The signature is

```
def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]]
```

I came up with the following solution

```
def sequence[A](l: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = {
  if (l.exists(_.isEmpty)) None
  else Some(l.map(_.get))
}
```

which does not seem to be perfect at all as it iterates the list and applies a `f` function twice to average 50% of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-functional-style with fast fail:

```
def sequence[A](xs: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = 
  Some(xs map (_.getOrElse(return None))) //this return (inside lambda) is implemented with exception in scala
```

Recursive one:

```
def sequence[A](xs: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = xs match {
  case Nil => None //or `Some(Nil)`
  case None :: tail => None
  case Some(head) :: Nil => Some(head :: Nil)
  case Some(head) :: tail => sequence(tail).map(head :: _) 
}
```

`Vector`-based `N` (not 1.5*N) steps, but without fast fail:

```
def sequence[A](xs: Vector[Option[A]]): Option[Vector[A]] = 
  Some(xs.flatten) filter (_.size == xs.size) //getting size is fast for vector
```

`Vector` + `view` based with fast fail:

```
//`view` doesn't create intermidiate collection and applies everything in one iteration
def sequence[A](xs: Vector[Option[A]]): Option[Seq[A]] = 
  Some(xs.view.takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).map(_.get).force) filter (_.size == xs.size)
```

Anyway, only performance tests will tell you the true about effectiveness here. All these algorithms (including yours) are linear O(N) and it's the best complexity you can get anyway. So, further optimizations may not worth it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick and dirty solution that is sure to offend everyone's good functional sensibilities :)

```
import scala.util.Try

def sequence[A](xs: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] =
  Try(xs.map(_.get)).toOption
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possibility:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = {
  @tailrec
  def seq(remaining: List[Option[A]], result: Option[List[A]]): Option[List[A]] = {
    if (remaining.isEmpty) {
      result
    } else {
      (remaining.head, result) match {
        case (Some(item), Some(list)) => seq(remaining.tail, Some(item :: list))
        case _ => None
      }    
    }
  }

  seq(a, Some(Nil))
}
```

It will stop evaluating the list as soon as it hits the first `None` element. And should return the same result as your implementation. However, it is important to **note** that this implementation will return Some(Nil) for an empty input list.

The implementation can be shortened a bit, depending on your preferences about expressiveness and other readability criteria:

```
def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = {
  @tailrec
  def seq(remaining: List[Option[A]], result: Option[List[A]]): Option[List[A]] = {
      (remaining, result) match {
        case (Nil, _) => result
        case (Some(item) :: tail, Some(list)) => seq(tail, Some(item :: list))
        case _ => None
      }
  }

  seq(a, Some(Nil))
}
```

The result will `Some` list in reverse order or `None`. If you want to preserve the list order you will have to

1. replace `seq(a, Some(Nil))` with `seq(a, Some(Nil)).map(_.reverse)`
2. or replace `item :: list` with `list :+ item`.

Though, `list :+ item` is not the optimal way to append items to a `List`. If you want to preserve the order and use a '@tailrec' approach I would recommend to use a `Vector` as result type instead of a `List`.

Comment: You are missing a `.map(_.reverse)` on the result. Also you can merge the two `None` match cases into `_ => None` and put them after the `Some` case.

Comment: Edited my answer with a remark about the list order. However, if I'd apply your second suggestion, I'd have to give up  `@tailrec`, would'nt I.

Comment: No, to be tail recursive the recusrive call does not have to be in the latest match statement, just the last statement in that particular case.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
def sequence[A](xs: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = xs match {
    case x :: xs => // Get one element at a time (Opton[A])
        for {
            a <- x // unwrap the Option[A] to A
            as <- sequence(xs) // Unwrap the recursive result of Option[List[A]] into List[A]
        } yield a :: as // Merge the elements and warp in Option
    case _ => Some(Nil) // sequence of an empty list is Some(List())
}
```

---

```
println(sequence(List[Some[Int]]())) // Some(List())
println(sequence(List(Some(1), None, Some(3)))) // None
println(sequence(List(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3)))) // Some(List(1, 2, 3))
```